# How to realize ajax on a form element with autocomplete

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a form textfield element, which contains autocomplete feature using #autocomplete_route_name.

Could you clarify me, how to call ajax function when the textfield value has been set via autocomplete ? That is, for example, an user has selected a value from the autocomplete list, set it into the textbox and right away something should be executed via ajax depending on new value of the textbox.

Which ajax event should I use for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution.
My code works with an event "autocompleteselect".

Here's an example of code

```
$form['autocomplete_field'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Autocomplete search'),
            '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'autocomplete_route',
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => '::ajaxFunctionAfterAutocomplete',
                'event' => 'autocompleteselect',
            ]
        ];
```